# magento reindexall fails with same SQL syntax error on 2 indexes

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, mysql-5.6

This command:

```
sudo php /var/www/shell/indexer.php -reindexall
```

fails on 2 indexes with the same SQL syntax error

> Catalog Search Index

And later

> Lucene Search Index

On catalogue Search Index, the condition ‘ciss.website_id = ’ looks like the syntax error. Here is the offending script:

```
SELECT `main`.`linked_product_id`
FROM `catalog_product_link` AS `main`
INNER JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_status` AS `ciss`
                ON ciss.product_id = main.product_id
    AND ciss.website_id =  WHERE (main.product_id = '5336')
    AND (link_type_id=3) AND (ciss.stock_status = 1)'
```

If I run this next script in MySQL Workbench with ‘ciss.website_id = 1’ instead instead of  ‘ciss.website_id = ’ it runs OK! (in order to test in workbench, I also removed the single inverted commas that magento seems to have in all SQL ).

```
SELECT main.linked_product_id
FROM catalog_product_link AS main
INNER JOIN cataloginventory_stock_status AS ciss
                ON ciss.product_id = main.product_id
    AND ciss.website_id = 1 WHERE (main.product_id = '5336')
    AND (link_type_id=3) AND (ciss.stock_status = 1);
```

The question is why does it fail to pick up a valid website_id (we have 1 and only 1 for our one shop)?

We recently upgraded from Magento 1.7.0.2 to 1.9.3.2 everything else is working OK.

Do we need to drop and re-create these two indexes?

Reindex also fails for catalogue search index via the Magento admin console.

HERE’S THE WHOLE STACK TRACE FOR THE INDEXER ERROR

```
prompt>sudo php /var/www/shell/indexer.php -reindexall
Product Attributes index was rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Product Prices index was rebuilt successfully in 00:00:01
Catalog URL Rewrites index was rebuilt successfully in 00:02:17
Category Products index was rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Catalog Search Index index process unknown error:
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE (main.product_id = '5336') AND (link_type_id=3) AND (ciss.stock_status = 1' at line 2' in /var/www/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 /var/www/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#2 /var/www/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#3 /var/www/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#4 /var/www/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `main`.`...', Array)
#5 /var/www/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(504): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `main`.`...', Array)
#6 /var/www/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(794): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
#7 /var/www/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Resource/Fulltext.php(609): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchCol(Object(Varien_Db_Select))
#8 /var/www/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Resource/Fulltext.php(624): Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext->_getProductChildrenIds('5336', 'grouped')
#9 /var/www/app/code/community/Php4u/BlastLuceneSearch/Model/Mysql4/Lucene.php(19) : eval()'d code(1) : eval()'d code(1) : eval()'d code(18): Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext->_getProductChildIds('5336', 'grouped')
#10 /var/www/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Resource/Fulltext.php(117): Php4u_BlastLuceneSearch_Model_Mysql4_Lucene->_rebuildStoreIndex(1, NULL)
#11 /var/www/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Fulltext.php(84): Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext->rebuildIndex(NULL, NULL)
#12 /var/www/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Indexer/Fulltext.php(455): Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Fulltext->rebuildIndex()
#13 /var/www/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(212): Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Indexer_Fulltext->reindexAll()
#14 /var/www/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(260): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#15 /var/www/shell/indexer.php(168): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#16 /var/www/shell/indexer.php(216): Mage_Shell_Compiler->run()
#17 {main}
 
Next exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE (main.product_id = '5336') AND (link_type_id=3) AND (ciss.stock_status = 1' at line 2, query was: SELECT `main`.`linked_product_id` FROM `catalog_product_link` AS `main`
INNER JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_status` AS `ciss` ON ciss.product_id = main.product_id AND ciss.website_id =  WHERE (main.product_id = '5336') AND (link_type_id=3) AND (ciss.stock_status = 1)' in /var/www/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:235
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /var/www/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /var/www/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /var/www/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `main`.`...', Array)
#4 /var/www/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(504): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `main`.`...', Array)
#5 /var/www/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(794): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
#6 /var/www/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Resource/Fulltext.php(609): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchCol(Object(Varien_Db_Select))
#7 /var/www/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Resource/Fulltext.php(624): Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext->_getProductChildrenIds('5336', 'grouped')
#8 /var/www/app/code/community/Php4u/BlastLuceneSearch/Model/Mysql4/Lucene.php(19) : eval()'d code(1) : eval()'d code(1) : eval()'d code(18): Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext->_getProductChildIds('5336', 'grouped')
#9 /var/www/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Resource/Fulltext.php(117): Php4u_BlastLuceneSearch_Model_Mysql4_Lucene->_rebuildStoreIndex(1, NULL)
#10 /var/www/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Fulltext.php(84): Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext->rebuildIndex(NULL, NULL)
#11 /var/www/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Indexer/Fulltext.php(455): Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Fulltext->rebuildIndex()
#12 /var/www/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(212): Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Indexer_Fulltext->reindexAll()
#13 /var/www/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(260): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#14 /var/www/shell/indexer.php(168): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#15 /var/www/shell/indexer.php(216): Mage_Shell_Compiler->run()
#16 {main}
Stock Status index was rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Tag Aggregation Data index was rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Lucene Search Index index process unknown error:
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE (main.product_id = '5336') AND (link_type_id=3) AND (ciss.stock_status = 1' at line 2' in /var/www/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 /var/www/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#2 /var/www/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#3 /var/www/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#4 /var/www/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `main`.`...', Array)
#5 /var/www/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(504): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `main`.`...', Array)
#6 /var/www/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(794): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
#7 /var/www/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Resource/Fulltext.php(609): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchCol(Object(Varien_Db_Select))
#8 /var/www/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Resource/Fulltext.php(624): Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext->_getProductChildrenIds('5336', 'grouped')
#9 /var/www/app/code/community/Php4u/BlastLuceneSearch/Model/Mysql4/Lucene.php(19) : eval()'d code(1) : eval()'d code(1) : eval()'d code(18): Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext->_getProductChildIds('5336', 'grouped')
#10 /var/www/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Resource/Fulltext.php(117): Php4u_BlastLuceneSearch_Model_Mysql4_Lucene->_rebuildStoreIndex(1, NULL)
#11 /var/www/app/code/community/Php4u/BlastLuceneSearch/Model/Lucene.php(19) : eval()'d code(1) : eval()'d code(1) : eval()'d code(18): Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext->rebuildIndex(NULL, NULL)
#12 /var/www/app/code/community/Php4u/BlastLuceneSearch/Model/Indexer/Product.php(19) : eval()'d code(1) : eval()'d code(1) : eval()'d code(18): Php4u_BlastLuceneSearch_Model_Lucene->rebuildIndex()
#13 /var/www/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(212): Php4u_BlastLuceneSearch_Model_Indexer_Product->reindexAll()
#14 /var/www/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(260): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#15 /var/www/shell/indexer.php(168): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#16 /var/www/shell/indexer.php(216): Mage_Shell_Compiler->run()
#17 {main}
 
Next exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE (main.product_id = '5336') AND (link_type_id=3) AND (ciss.stock_status = 1' at line 2, query was: SELECT `main`.`linked_product_id` FROM `catalog_product_link` AS `main`
INNER JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_status` AS `ciss` ON ciss.product_id = main.product_id AND ciss.website_id =  WHERE (main.product_id = '5336') AND (link_type_id=3) AND (ciss.stock_status = 1)' in /var/www/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:235
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /var/www/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /var/www/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /var/www/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `main`.`...', Array)
#4 /var/www/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(504): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `main`.`...', Array)
#5 /var/www/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(794): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
#6 /var/www/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Resource/Fulltext.php(609): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchCol(Object(Varien_Db_Select))
#7 /var/www/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Resource/Fulltext.php(624): Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext->_getProductChildrenIds('5336', 'grouped')
#8 /var/www/app/code/community/Php4u/BlastLuceneSearch/Model/Mysql4/Lucene.php(19) : eval()'d code(1) : eval()'d code(1) : eval()'d code(18): Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext->_getProductChildIds('5336', 'grouped')
#9 /var/www/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Resource/Fulltext.php(117): Php4u_BlastLuceneSearch_Model_Mysql4_Lucene->_rebuildStoreIndex(1, NULL)
#10 /var/www/app/code/community/Php4u/BlastLuceneSearch/Model/Lucene.php(19) : eval()'d code(1) : eval()'d code(1) : eval()'d code(18): Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext->rebuildIndex(NULL, NULL)
#11 /var/www/app/code/community/Php4u/BlastLuceneSearch/Model/Indexer/Product.php(19) : eval()'d code(1) : eval()'d code(1) : eval()'d code(18): Php4u_BlastLuceneSearch_Model_Lucene->rebuildIndex()
#12 /var/www/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(212): Php4u_BlastLuceneSearch_Model_Indexer_Product->reindexAll()
#13 /var/www/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(260): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#14 /var/www/shell/indexer.php(168): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#15 /var/www/shell/indexer.php(216): Mage_Shell_Compiler->run()
#16 {main}
```